# Adding items to array from variable PHP OOP

Tags: php, arrays, oop

I am trying to add an item into an array from a variable.

```
class MyClassName {
public $key = '1234abcd';
public $email = 'example@example.tld';

var $header = array(
    "Content-Type: application/json",
    "KEY: " . $this->key,
    "EMAIL: " . $this->email
);  // code continued .....
```

For some reason, when I run that code, it gives me an error saying `syntax error, unexpected '$this' (T_VARIABLE)`.

Did I assign the variable incorrectly?

Comment: You have to move your `var $header ...` into a `__constructor` http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making a constructor solved the problem as mentioned by @joaumg -

```
public $key = '1234abcd';
public $email = 'example@example.tld';
public $header = array();

function __construct() {
    $this->header = array(
        "Content-Type: application/json",
        "KEY: " . $this->key,
        "EMAIL: " . $this->email
    );
}
```

[php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php)